# how to implement openwith in winrt xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

i am working on pdf viewer kind app in winrt.
it is almost done .but i want to add a feature that 
when user RIGHT click on any pdf File in win32 there should be an option to open with my reader. can any one please tell me how to achive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable your application to handle the pdf file type. You can do this by double-clicking on the application manifest file in Visual Studio. In the *Declarations* tab, add a new *File Type Association*. Then fill in the fields for the file association.

For example, the following adds an association for the ".myfile" extension:

[image: declaration-file-assoc]

The other thing that needs to be done is that you must in code handle the [OnFileActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onfileactivated.aspx) event handler. This will be called whenever the end user opens a file with the associated extension from Explorer.

Note that for the file association to work, your application must be run at least once.

See the following link for more info on associating a file type: [How to handle file activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779669.aspx)

Comment: it's working fine while initilizing the main page how to get the parameter as file

Comment: I am not totally sure of what you are saying, but the files are given to your application in the OnFileActivated event.